# WSO2 Identity Server 5.11.0 (Linux) - OAuth2 - CORS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I know this is a known problem but it seems new version v5.11.0 brings another problem related to CORS.

According to this [documentation](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/invoking-an-endpoint-from-a-different-domain/), you just need to configure CORS behavior to make call from application out of I.S. domain.

I did this configuration, but it doesn't work. When I call endpoint `/oauth2/oidcdiscovery/.well-known/openid-configuration`, I get following error:

```
    Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxx:9443/oauth2/oidcdiscovery/.well-known/openid-configuration' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Does anybody facing same problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow this cors configuration given in this [doc](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/cors/#cors-configurations). From 5.11 onwards, IS has changed the cors configuration model. Check the new changes done for 5.11 [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/migrating-what-has-changed/#what-has-changed).  So the configuration mentioned in this [documentation](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/invoking-an-endpoint-from-a-different-domain/)
is no longer valid

Comment: Yeah, you're right... Now you need to configure CORS in deployment.toml. Thank you!